# git rebase --onto : not doing what I thought it does

Tags: git, git-rebase

So, I'm obviously not using the commands properly, but I am having trouble figuring out exactly *which* command I need to type to achieve what I want to do:

Consider a sprint branch, let's call it `Team_Sprint_5`.  On day 1 of the sprint, I create a new branch to work my issue: `Issue-1234-branch`.  So far, so good. My branch has a base of the `Team_Sprint_5` branch:

Commit History at Branch Creation:

```
5825d  <-- Team_Sprint_5 & feature branch head
3fc55  older commit
a3911  even older commit
```

So, I do a commit. Now my branch looks like this:

```
2c442  <-- My commit
5825d  <-- Issue-1234-branch Base
3fc55  
a3911
```

Meanwhile, the main sprint branch has been updated. **I would like to move my branch to be at the tip of the current sprint branch**:

```
(2c442) <-- I want my commit to move here
 b6740  <-- updated Team_Sprint_5 head
 a77fb
 ...    <-- several additional commits in the main branch
[2c442] <-- where my commit ends up instead
 5825d  <-- Where we originally started
```

So, from my current branch, I used `git rebase --onto b6740`. However, that seemed to smash all the commits between my initial branch creation on top of the commit made in my branch, which is not what I intended. **What is the appropriate command to do what I need?**

**Edit:**
What I ended up doing, since I messed up my branch beyond my simple ability to fix it, is to create a new branch from the tip of the current sprint branch, then picked my commit using the `cherry-pick` command. I have to believe this can be done with a simple rebase on the original branch though.

Comment: Could you post a tree of before and after what you have? That would help visualize, though I think you just want `git rebase b6740` while standing on your local branch.

Comment: So leave out the --onto? And I don't understand what you mean by "tree" - I've put the commit history in there in reverse-chronological order.

Comment: Yes, remove the `onto`. I mean a visual representation of all discussed branches, so we better understand what commit was smashed (or if you have another way to show it that would be fine as well).

Comment: @kabanus - please see my edit... hopefully that is clearer

Comment: Ah yes, thanks. I'm not sure of my initial suggestion now.

Comment: So which branch head was advanced by commit `2c442`? That seems to be the crucial bit of information that is missing. A tip: the output of `git log --graph --decorate --all --oneline` is useful for reasoning about how to perform various rebases. (`--all` can be replaced with one or more specific branches if `--all` includes too much information.)

Comment: It *looks* like you don't really need a rebase, but just a fast-forward merge of an appropriate branch. I'm assuming `2c442` is not the parent of any commit.

Comment: `2c442` was on my local feature branch.

Comment: You want to rebase your `Issue-1234-branch` on top of `Team_Sprint_5`, not move your commit directly on top. Eventually, you will *merge* `Issue-1234-branch` back into `Team_Sprint_5`, but rebasing can simplify the merge by letting you resolve some merge conflicts early before too many conflicts pile up.

Comment: @chepner - I wanted to resolve the merge conflicts, which is why I did this in the first place - someone else had some stuff integrated into the `Team` branch that I wanted, so I needed to step my branch up... I don't know if the answer you posted helps me get there

Answer (score 1):

I think you started here, with something like

```
* b6740 (Team_5_Sprint)
* a77fb
|
* * 2c442 (Issue-1234-branch)
|/
* 5825d
* 3fc55  
* a3911
```

Then `git rebase Team_5_Sprint Issue-1234-branch` (no `--onto` needed) would have resulted in

```
* vwxyz (Issue-1234-branch)  # "Copy" of 2c442
* b6740 (Team_5_Sprint)
* a77fb
| * 2c442
|/
* 5825d
* 3fc55  
* a3911
```

(for some new commit `vwxyz`; your original commit `2c442` is now a dangling commit eligible for garbage collection, but still retrievable via the reflog.).

Before `vwxyz` can be created from `2c442`, you may need to resolve some merge conflicts.

---

Here's an example of when `--onto` is necessary, from `git help rebase`:

```
          o---o---o---o---o  master
                \
                 o---o---o---o---o  next
                                  \
                                   o---o---o  topic
```

Using `git rebase --onto master next topic`, we move the commits between `next` and `topic` on top of `master`:

```
         o---o---o---o---o  master
               |            \
               |             o'--o'--o'  topic
                \
                 o---o---o---o---o  next
```

Without `--onto`, using `git rebase master topic`, you would end up copying
all of `next` (since `next` and `topic` share the same branch point off of `master`) on top of `master`:

```
          o---o---o---o---o  master
               \           \
                \           o'--o'--o'--o'--o'--o'--o'--o'  topic
                 \
                  o---o---o---o---o  next
```

(The first 5 commits immediately after `master` are the "same" commits tha make up `next`.)

Comment: So, had I done `rebase` (no `--onto`), I would have ended up with a new commit copied from the old commit, but stepped up to the current main branch? Vs. what I did when I created the new branch it picked the same commit? I don't know if I care about a dangling branch, but is there a way to do it without creating a new commit? To be clear, my new branch has, as it's latest commit, the 2c442 commit.

Comment: I think what you did had the same result; this is just the "cleaner" way of getting there.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm looking for. What I did was a pain, and this is the second time! The first time, I ended up with 20 commits to rebase.